# I can't remove whistespace

Tags: python, sqlite

I have json file which is inserted in a sqlite database.

After inserting, all non breaking space are automatically converted to whitespace, which is good!

**json file looks like** : `[{'john' : "6\u00a0500\u00a0\u20ac" , 'dams' : "7\u00a0500\u00a0\u20ac"}, {'john' : "10\u00a0900\u00a0\u20ac" , 'dams' : "13\u00a0980\u00a0\u20ac"}] ##style it in code block`

**sqlite file looks like**:

[image]

My goal is to remove whitespace, '€' and cast the value to integer. 
I used `trim`, `ltrim`, `rtrim`, `replace` and combinations of `trim` and `replace` to remove whitespace, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The Python command is `strip`; `trim` is Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would suggest that you ensure that you're using double quotes throughout your JSON files. This is the standard for JSON syntax and moreover, not having things consistent will cause more of a headache later on.

With that out of the way, here's my solution:

```py
with open(jsonFile, "r") as file:
    jsonLines = file.readlines()

cleanJsonLines = []
for jsonDict in jsonLines:
    for key in jsonDict:
        almostCleanJson = jsonDict[key].replace("\u00a0", "")
        cleanJson = almostCleanJson.replace("\u20ac", "")

        cleanJsonLines.append({key: cleanJson})

print(cleanJsonLines)
```

Output:

```
[{'john': '6500'}, {'dams': '7500'}]
```